# What are the quests that end each chapter in The Witcher 1

Tags: the-witcher

I'm a bit of a completionist so I hate missing quests, so I'd like to do all the secondary quests before ending the chapter. After ending chapter 1 and finding I missed some quests, I had to load an old saved game and replay part of the chapter.

I found a list of quests by chapter in the [Witcher wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_quests) but checking them to see if it might end the chapter might spoil me a bit of the story.

So I'd like to know what are the quests that will end each chapter and prevent me to do all the secondary quests of that chapter, in order to complete the other ones before heading to that path.

For example, I think that the chapter 1 secondary quests should be done before the phase [Waiting for a Solution](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Of_Monsters_and_Men#Waiting_for_a_Solution) of the quest [Of Monsters and Men](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Of_Monsters_and_Men).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each chapter has a few key 'point of no return' moments:

In Chapter 1, as you noted, *Of Monsters and Men* is your final quest.

Chapter 2 ends with the opening of the *Mysterious Tower*/the placing of the ten stones in the monoliths. However, the key moment you'll want to delay to avoid closing out sidequests is completing the autopsy - doing it too soon can lock out some other investigative paths for *Vizima Confidential* and related sidequests.

The easiest way to avoid finishing Chapter 3 too early is to simply delay attending the *Posh Reception* at the New Narakort. You can finish the vast majority of side quests before attending - all that's left afterwards is either Primary Quests, turn-ins to NPC's who were at the reception, and a single sidequest which is completed by running through the main quest after doing some earlier footwork.

Chapter 4 is a bit cleaner; the two main quests that must be completed to advance are *Ripples* and *The Heat of the Day* -  once those two are finished, the landscape will shift dramatically and you'll have trouble completing further sidequests.

And finally, Chapter 5 is extremely linear - the final quest, *Sweet Revenge* is nearly impossible to encounter without having passed through the rest of the chapter and done whatever else is there to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite a necro-posting, but still I'll clarify this for people who get here from a search engine:
In Chapter 2, you only have to avoid completing Posh reception until you complete the Echoef of Yesterday and Six Feet Under quests. If you complete Posh Reception first, you will be only able to complete one of them. I don't like delaying Posh reception for too long because it forces you to pile up complete quests only to turn them in in bulk, what sucks especially if you are short on money.

The quest that ends the Chapter is The Unforgiven, with the point of no return being relatively early (won't say specific trigger to avoid spoiling), so once you get this quest, don't advance it until you have done everything you wanted.